# Is there a way to duplicate the number of NSDictionaries in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I currently have this array of `NSDictionary`s in my table view, but I need to duplicate the number of dictionaries in the array as the table view scrolls down. Is there a way to achieve this, and also specify or know what the dictionary names will be?

```
NSMutableDictionary *d0 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *d1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *d2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *d3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *d4 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, nil];
```

Comment: What does "duplicate the number" mean? Describe what you want to happen.

Comment: I want a way to create new dictionaries i.e. d5, d6, d7, d8, d9 and then add them to the array.

Comment: What stops you from doing that?

Comment: I need it happen automatically, as the next page loads in my table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it seams to be easier to create the dictionaries in a loop:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
   [objects addObject:[NSMutableDictionary new]];
}
```

If you want to "duplicate" the dictionaries, you can do that with a loop, too:

```
for( NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in [objects copy])
{
  [objects addObject:[dictionary mutableCopy]];
}
```

But I cannot get rid of the feeling that your whole approach is wrong. What is the idea behind that?

Comment: Here's a video of what I'm trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6xPcxaTdF8 But I also need to load new objects to the array as the user scrolls down.